Is the given Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption over Integers still viable and fast?
In the paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf
They talk about a public key SWHE over Integers scheme that is pretty simple (I do not care about the FHE aspect of the paper).
I was wondering if there have been any attacked found on it?
Also is this scheme considered efficient? From what it seems compared to other SWHE schemes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) encryption seems to be fast as long as you can generate the public keys quickly and the addition operation also seems fast.
The reason I care about this scheme is due to the addition operation (I do not need to perform any multiplications on my ciphers and the amount of addition operations I have to perform are very small or zero) and the fact that the public key can be used to randomize a ciphertext such that the new cipher looks different than before (You can do this by just adding a subset sum of the public keys to the cipher which will not modify the message but make the cipher look different).
The last property to me is very important.
Lastly is there any way of generating the public keys efficiently? And the prime p?


They talk about a public key SWHE over Integers scheme that is pretty simple

It is not that simple, though this is non-obvious. It requires a prime $p$ of bit-precision $\eta$ which is large. As an example, this paper sets $p$ to have $\log p\approx \eta = 192$ to achieve 72 bits of security (smaller than typically thought reasonable). This means you'll have to implement big-integer arithmetic securely, which was always a massive pain point of secure implementations of RSA/DLOG-based cryptography.
By contrast, other similar somewhat homomorphic encryption schemes (based on LWE or RLWE) can use pretty small moduli, so you can avoid this.

I was wondering if there have been any attacked found on it?

No. It is based on the hardness of the "Approximate GCD" problem (as well as an additional assumption to be made fully homomorphic). This is known to be as hard as the Learning with Errors problem (similarly to the other LWE and RLWE-based schemes), which is still thought to be secure.

Also is this scheme considered efficient?

Not particularly. While you don't care about FHE, it can be a useful benchmark. Here is an AGCD scheme implementing a very specific algorithm that is of technical interest. It claims to take < 1 second. Competing RLWE-based algorithms typically take < 50ms (I've seen claims as fast as ~5 ms lately). So it is much slower than other techniques (which are admittedly better-studied, but part of that is because they are much faster).

The public key can be used to randomize a ciphertext such that the new cipher looks different than before

This can be done for any somewhat homomorphic encryption scheme. Namely, givern a ciphertext $c$ encrypting $m$, one can always add a ciphertext $c'$ encrypting 0. For the various somewhat homomorphic encryption schemes I've mentioned above (based on LWE/RLWE), the ciphertext $c + c'$ will look random to someone who has knowledge of $c$ but not $c'$. So to rerandomize your ciphertext $c$, generate a fresh encryption $c'$ of 0, add it to $c$, and then throw it away.
All in all, there's no real reason to not use an RLWE-based somewhat homomorphic encryption scheme. It probably makes sense to just use a pre-existing library. You can find links to some here. I would just pick one that is written in a language you like personally. The fact that many of the libraries (also) support FHE should not matter for your application. When used for somewhat homomorphic encryption, they are all highly efficient.
The only real caveat to that is if you care about small ciphertexts specifically. This can still be achieved for the application you have in mind, but I don't remember the libraries having that great of support. Expect things in the 1 - 10KB range at the smallest. If you care about getting smaller than this, using other forms of somewhat homomorphic encryption (look up the "Pallier" scheme, or "Damgard-Jurik") which requires a larger amount of computation, may be appropriate.

Is there any FHE encryption scheme that can be 'embedded' into a Finite Field? As using the scheme given in the original paper it may be possible to do so but if it is based in LWE it may be impossible (I think). For example can you convert a cipher from BFV into an element of a Finite Field?

@CLox are you asking if the message space can be embedded into a finite field or the ciphertext space? Both are (pretty easily) true, but I'd need more details to give you more details. Anyway though, messages in RLWE are elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$ for $f(x)$ a monic irreducible polynomial, and $p$ (typically, at least for parameter regimes you indicate interest in) prime. This is to say that messages are exactly finite field elements.

Things aren't generally presented this way, as it requires the assumption that $q$ is prime, which isn't otherwise generally required, and is actually quite limiting in certain situations. Ciphertexts are pairs of elements $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(f(x))$ (for some $q > p$), so can be viewed as pairs of finite field elements. There are ways of viewing them as a single element (maybe of a finite field?) --- one recent "big" paper (best paper at STOC 2023 iirc) did precisely this as a key step in their construction.

Depending on what you precisely mean (what algebraic operations does the embedding have to respect), I expect one of these two things will suffice to answer "yes" to your question.

Thank You @Mark Schultz-Wu I really appreciate your help! I am talking about the ciphertext space being 'embedded' into a Finite Field. For the plaintext space I am only worried about encrypting '0' and when you have a ciphertext you should be able to re-randomize the ciphertext so that you can't correlate it back to the original cipher. I need this for a specific purpose.

Preferably if possible we have one ciphertext that can directly be represented as a element of a Finite Field? In the case of LWE it seems that you get ciphertext c=<c1,c2> where c1 is a vector (of length n if your A matrix is of size mxn) which has values from Zq hence can be represented in a Finite Field if the parameters are chosen correctly. Is this the same case with RLWE (or pretty close to it)?

Also the reason I am primarily looking into homomorphic scheme is because I can re-randomize the ciphertext such that the person who encrypted does not know what the original ciphertext was. For this 're-randomize' ability homomorphic encryption seems the only way forward but all the fast homomorphic encryption schemes have 'pairs' of ciphertexts which seem difficult to represent as a single element of a Finite Field.

Furthermore since I might even need to do millions of encryption using something like RLWE will that be efficient? This may sound dumb but if need to do millions of encryption of '0' would that still be efficient?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
